# Can not run the case of "Real Time Reporting with the Table API" in TryFlink

Tags: apache-flink

I just get start learning flink and try the case, "[Real Time Reporting with the Table API](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/try-flink/table_api/) "
When I ran docker-compose, all containers worked except jobmanager which is exited with 2.
[up all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16AwS.png)
[exit with 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZkip.png)
I tried rebuild and restart, but it does not work and I do not know what's wrong with it.
Could anyone help me to figure it out,please? Many thanks!

Comment: 2021-12-26 09:17:19,015 ERROR org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint        [] - Fatal error occurred in the cluster entrypoint.
org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: Application failed unexpectedly.
 at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.application.ApplicationDispatcherBootstrap.lambda$runApplicationAndShutdownClusterAsync$0(ApplicationDispatcherBootstrap.java:170) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.13.1.jar:1.13.1]

Answer (score 1):

This particular tutorial does fail if you skip ahead and try to run it without first providing an implementation for org.apache.flink.playgrounds.spendreport.SpendReport.report. Several versions of that method are provided in the tutorial: pick one (perhaps the last one), drop it in, rebuild the docker image, and try again.